# Refresh with POST data

Tags: php, post, refresh, hidden-field

I am using the following php

```
header("Refresh: 0;url=thankyou.htm");
```

I want to add a hidden variable with that refresh so I must add something like.....

```
<input type=hidden name='varname' value="<?php echo $variable;?>">
```

How can I post the hidden variable to the refresh page?

How can these be combined?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use session variable instead of hidden field.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['var'] = $variable ; 

header("Refresh: 0;url=thankyou.htm");
```

in the thank_you page get the variable to retrieve...

EDIT: destroy session if required using session_destroy();

Comment: I do not know when a session variable gets cleared or expires. I do not want that user to come back later and have that session variable still valid. I am trying to find a way to determine if a person came back via bookmark or favourite, or whether they used the javascript pop up as the page needs to behave differently

Comment: You need to pass a variable to thank you page. ($_GET/$_POST antthing can be used)How are you getting the "$variable" from php...?

Comment: I just figured out how to destroy the session and it appears to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's secret enough but you could encrypt the variable and send as a `$_GET`:

```
header("Refresh: 0;url=thankyou.htm?varname=".base64_encode($_POST['varname']));
```

On the `thankyou.htm` page you would have to `base64_decode()` to get the value back.

Using a `session` will work behind the scenes for "most secret" as **@Riad** suggests.

Comment: No type of URL variable will work as I am trying to determine if the user came back by bookmark/favorite or if they came via tha javascript pop up window. Any URL variable will be maintained through a bookmark/favorite

Comment: Ah, well to persist a page variable on a `header()` has to be passed by `$_GET` or session variable or you have to `include()` the thank you page instead of redirecting to it.